# Android local notification in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, localnotification

Unity has their own class and method for iOS local notification but not for Android.
So can anyone suggest me how to implement Android local notifications in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Notification Service](http://www.insalgo.com/en/products/notification-service) plugin available on [Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12808) for local notifications (+ lot more) in Unity. The price is 15$ but it’s totally worth it - according to users reviews.

I am co-author so feel free to ask me questions.