# Local notifications with Unity (Firebase?)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, uilocalnotification

Is there an easy way to implement **local notifications** from the Unity client?

I'm using Firebase for handling our **push notifications** (which are sent from our server), but I was wondering if there is an easy way to support local notifications?

I found this question: [Firebase local notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569816/firebase-local-notifications)
But it is specifically to iOS.

I was wondering if there is a solution for Unity (without the need to write some iOS and Android plugins) where I can schedule local notifications from the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for iOS you can do it directly from Unity, without iOS native code (like presented [here](https://www.gamegorillaz.com/blog/how-to-send-local-push-notifications/)).

For Android, you can use an existing plugin, like [this](https://github.com/Agasper/unity-android-notifications), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433361/android-local-notification-in-unity/24920562#24920562)